# Get index of focused cell and set focus programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

I am developing an Android App where I have a **TableLayout** and each cell has an **EditText** in it. I want to navigate through the cells using four buttons.  For example: Two buttons for up-down navigation (same column, different rows) and two buttons for left-right navigation (same row, different columns).  Then I want to highlight the cell that has the focus at that moment (e.g. by changing the background color of that **EditText**).

I want to know if there is a way I can set the focus (for navigation) programmatically and get the index of the focused cell (for highlighting)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @TheGeekYouNeed. Android in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use View.requestFocus() to force focus to a view. For the index, you can use a variable for each axis. For example, everytime the right button is pressed you can increase the value of your x-axis variable by 1. And decrease when the left button is pressed. You should initialize those axis variables correctly.